# Using webkit CSS styles in Qt 4.8.6

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I am trying to apply a the following webkit CSS styles to some Qt elements

```
text-shadow                  : 0.20em 0.20em 0.20em #999;
-webkit-text-stroke-color    : #000000;
-webkit-text-stroke-width    : 1px;
-webkit-text-fill-color      : purple;
```

However I keep getting the error messages:

```
Unknown property text-shadow
Unknown property -webkit-text-stroke-color
Unknown property -webkit-text-stroke-width
Unknown property -webkit-text-fill-color
```

I am using Qt 4.8.6, which I believe supports webkit.

Comment: You may research this - https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/stylesheet-reference.html#id-db91e26c-a488-4622-926b-076dac7c42d9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webkit is a component or widget in Qt 4.8. That means you can embed a Webkit browser (just like you could use a text field or a scene graph). It doesn't mean that every element in Qt supports Webkit's CSS styles.